# Maximum and minimum exponents in double-precision floating-point format

Tags: floating-point, numbers, precision, exponent, numeric-limits

According to the [IEEE Std 754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754_revision) standard, the exponent field width of the binary64 double-precision floating-point format is 11 bits, which is compensated by an exponent bias of 1023. The standard also specifies that the maximum exponent is 1023, and the minimum is -1022. Why is the maximum exponent not:

```
2^10 + 2^9 + 2^8 + 2^7 + 2^6 + 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 - 1023 = 1024
```

And the minimum exponent not:

```
0 - 1023 = -1023
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bits for the exponent have two reserved values, one for encoding `0` and subnormal numbers, and one for encoding ∞ and NaNs. As a result of this, the range of normal exponents is two smaller than you would otherwise expect. See §3.4 of the IEEE-754 standard (`w` is the number of bits in the exponent — `11` in the case of `binary64`):

> The range of the encoding's biased exponent E shall include:
>
> ― Every integer between 1 and 2<sup>w</sup> – 2, inclusive, to encode normal numbers
>
> ― The reserved value 0 to encode ±0 and subnormal numbers
>
> ― The reserved value 2<sup>w</sup> – 1 to encode ±∞ and NaNs.

Comment: So is the exponent `1024` the one reserved for ±∞ and NaNs, and the exponent `-1023` the one for ±0 and subnormal numbers? If so, then is the exponent `-1023` defined as `0`?

Comment: By the way, the section you are referring to is §3.4 (in the official IEEE document).

Comment: So is there a minimum exponent width you could ever have? Does it make sense to have an exponent that is 0 bits? 1 bits? 2 bits?